# Can you use generated access codes to log users in Firebase Auth?

Tags: firebase, authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I want to allow access codes (ABC123DEF456) to sign a user in to Google Firebase Auth. Is that possible? No other fields, just a form for the code.

I plan to create user accounts tied to their emails, and send them access codes through a link in their email. They can sign-in directly after clicking on the link, or type the access code on the web page.

I could use Firestore to check their access codes if it's tied to an email and log them in. Any help on this?

Comment: How are you generating that access code ?

Comment: Manually generated @Kundan

Comment: I think that could be implemented in the similar manner where people user `username` instead of `emailId` for login.

Comment: For what you mention, you want a similar functionality as https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens, is that correct? If that's the case, there are some examples in the docs for it. Let me know if I'm missunderstanding your question

Comment: I was thinking that too @Kundan, their email is the username, and the access code is the password.

Comment: @rsalinas - I want to log them in as they click on the email link, or when they enter an access code on the form. I might need more clarification as the link you sent me is after the log-in process

Comment: So you are refering more to something like this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth, or something like a custom auth token https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth#authenticate-with-firebase, is this correct?